# Clojure write 2d array to csv

Tags: csv, clojure

I understand how to write to CSV using `[clojure.data.csv]` But I am at a loss as to write the CSV in this specific format.

The data I want to write to CSV is the result of a DB query using  `[clojure.java.jdbc]` with the `as-arrays? true` modifier which returns a 2D array where `[0][1]` is the `column names` which need to become the `headers` in the CSV and then `[x][y]` will become the data to write to these headers so `[1][0]` will write the first returned row and column 0 to the CSV under the first heading.

```
(with-open [out-file (io/writer "out-file.csv")]
  (csv/write-csv out-file
       [["abc" "def"]
        ["ghi" "jkl"]]))
```

The above is an example of writing to CSV file, but I am unsure how to use the result of my query and write the values to CSV.

The data will look like this:

```
[[header1, header2, header3]
 [val1, val2, val3]
 [val1, val2, val3]]
```

The query looks like this:

```
(j/query db ["$SOME_QUERY"] as-arrays? true))
```

Can somebody help with this?

Edit: update this is what i have so far:

```
(defn write-query-to-csv [query db output-filename]
  (log/info (str "Executing " query " on " db))
  (let [results (j/query db ["$QUERY"]
                         :as-arrays? true)
        header (->> results
                    first)
        data (->> results)]
    (with-open [out-file (io/writer output-filename)]
      (csv/write-csv out-file
                     (reduce conj (conj [] header) data)))
    (io/file output-filename)))
```

The header data is correct but I'm unsure how to populate the data variabale :/

Comment: `s/FILL THIS IN/rest/`?

Comment: @cfrick That was a bad copy paste from me, it shouldn't be in there!

Comment: It looks to me like data is a sequence of sequences, and in the `let` you pull the header sequence out, but don't strip it off of the data.  So now `header` contains a sequence of header labels, and `data` contains the header sequence plus the data sequences (one sequence for each row). The `reduce` line adds the header sequence back on to the sequence of sequences--which now contains two header sequences. It looks as if the `let` only needs to bind `result`, and then you can pass `result` with no modification as the second argument to `write-csv`.  That's it.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you say "the data will look like this", do you mean the data returned by `query`, or the data you want to write to the file?  That's why I can't post an answer--I'm not sure what `j/query` is returning.  If you mean, by that comment, the data that you want to write to the file, then what is `query` returning?  Take a look at it, if you're not sure.  (Add `(println result)`, for example.  If that's too much data, construct a different query, or use `take` to take only the first n rows.)  My guess is that `result` is in exactly the format that you want.

Comment: @Mars the query returns the data in the correct format, I was needless over processing it. If you want to mark passing the result to `write-csv` then that may help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like `results` is a sequence of sequences, and in the `let` you pull the header sequence out, but don't strip it off of the data. Then `header` contains a sequence of header labels, and `data` contains the header sequence plus the data sequences (one sequence for each row). The `reduce` line adds the header sequence back on to the sequence of sequences--which now contains two header sequences.  Most of that isn't necessary.  Since `results` is in the correct format for passing to `write-csv`, the `let` only needs to bind `results`, and then you can pass `results` with no modification as the second argument to `write-csv`, like this:

```
(defn write-query-to-csv [query db output-filename]
  (log/info (str "Executing " query " on " db))
  (let [results (j/query db ["$QUERY"]
                         :as-arrays? true)]
    (with-open [out-file (io/writer output-filename)]
      (csv/write-csv out-file result)
    (io/file output-filename)))
```

So you don't need the `reduce` line here, but for future reference, it would probably clearer to replace `(conj [] header)` with `(vector header)`.  Also, another way to write the entire `reduce` expression would be `(cons header data)`.  That will return a different kind of sequence than your `reduce` line, but `write-csv` won't care, and I think performance should be similar.  You could also use `(into (vector header) data)`.